# Структура базы данных друзей

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Я никак не пойму как правильно структурировать базу. Подскажите. 
Вот у меня есть таблица

`users`:

```
+----+------+-----------+-------+---------------+
| id | name | last_name | phone | friends_phone |
+----+------+-----------+-------+---------------+
|  1 | Петр |  Петров   | 66666 |     33333     |
+----+------+-----------+-------+---------------+
|  2 | Макс |  Васильев | 33333 |     66666     |
+----+------+-----------+-------+---------------+
```

и `friendship`

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+
| id | user_one_id | user_two_id | status|
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+
|  1 |     1       |     2       |   1   |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+
```

В поле `status`:
Если 0 - ожидание, 1 - принято, 2 - отклонено

Так вот, Петр Петров отправил запрос дружбы Максу Васильеву по его номеру телефона и `ID Петра` вставляется в таблицу `friendship` и `status` равен 0. В свою очередь Макс принимает запрос (Проверка пойдет, сравнение с номером Петра и тем номером, что вел Макс. Если совпадают, то и его `ID` вставится в таблицу и `статус` поменяется на 1)

Вопросы:

1) В данном случае, я могу предложить дружбу только одному человеку, где веду номер друга в таблице users `friends_phone`, как сделать чтобы можно было расширять `friends_phone`?

2) Мне кажется, добавлять поле `friends_phone` в таблице `users` не правильно, но как тогда иначе? Как проверять совпадение номеров при принятии дружбы и тд?

Comment: Не совсем понял. Вот например Петр отправляет запрос Максу и `ID` Петра подставляется в таблицу `friendship`. Макс ведет свой номер при регистрации и номер с кем хочет дружить или принять запрос. Сравниваем номер друга который вел Макс с тем что в таблице `friendship`, то есть номер Петра. Потом сравниваем номер Макса с тем, что вел Петр в таблице Users

Comment: Если не хотите заранее заводить пользователей, то тогда в таблицу friendship добавляете поле телефон. Если при запросе дружбы пользователь с указанным телефоном уже есть, то спокойно заполнаете в записи оба ID и все. Если же Петра еще нет, то user_one ставите 1 (Макс), user_two оставляете NULL (пользователя еще нет) в поле телефона в friendship фиксируете 5555. Когда Петр вводит свой номер телефона вы видите в friendship записи с таким номером и автоматом проставляете им всем user_two равный ID Петра, а телефон стираете

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ,  Глупонул. Первый вариант годится. Перенесите в ответ. Поставлю галку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поле friends_phone в таблице users не требуется. Предлагаю такой алгоритм действий, при добавлении дружбы: Пользователь ID1 хочет подружиться с пользователем у которого телефон 5555.

1. Если пользователь с таким телефоном в БД уже есть (пусть его ID=2) переходим к п. 3
2. Если пользователя с таким телефоном еще нет - мы его создаем (Пусть у него окажется ID=2), т.е. в таблицу users добавляем запись с таким телефоном. При этом остальные поля оставляем пустыми. Когда пользователь с телефоном 5555 захочет зарегистрироваться мы вместо создания новой записи начнем использовать вот эту.
3. Добавляем в таблицу friendship запись вида `user_one=1, user_two=2, status=0`.
4. Пользователю с ID=2, когда он уже зарегистрирован, показываем в приглашениях к дружбе все записи с user_two=2 и status=0

Comment: `При этом остальные поля оставляем пустыми` - то есть минус все контроли целостности... не великовата ли цена? Мне кажется, что заявка на установление дружбы и факт наличия дружбы должны быть выделены в две независимые сущности, и соответственно реализованы в виде отдельных таблиц.

Comment: @Akina Я предлагал и второй вариант, там в коментариях к вопросу. ТС принял первый. И собственно какие контроли целостности вы имеете ввиду. Там сейчас есть имя, фамилия и телефон. я предполагаю, что будет еще пароль, изначально я предлагал ориентироваться именно на отсутствие пароля. Если какие то поля для зарегистрированного пользователя являются обязательными - их наличие можно проверить при регистрации триггером

Comment: @Akina Если заявка отдельная сущность, то как она выглядит ? Что то мне подсказывает что точно так же как и установленная дружба только еще поле телефон есть при приглашении не зарегистрированного пользователя

Comment: Если заявка есть отдельная сущность, то, вероятно, она должна выглядеть как сущность с неопределённым набором атрибутов. Либо определённым, где ни один из атрибутов не является обязательным. Первое реализуется, скорее всего, как EAV, второе - как разреженная таблица. А найти и отобразить заявку на дружбу, направленную в текущий профиль - это уже забота программной части формы отображения запросов на дружбу (а для заявок, созданных текущим профилем - соответственно формы отображения статусов заявок).

Comment: @Akina Это конечно интересный вопрос отправления заявок на дружбу по произвольным атрибутам пользователя, Но лично я бы поостерегся делать запросы "на будущее" по какому то не ключевому атрибуту (т.е. не по номеру телефона). Либо пользователь уже есть в системе и я его нахожу поиском по любым атрибутам и отправляю запрос именно тому, кому хочу (по ID). Либо, если пользователя еще нет, оставляю заявку на будущее (по факту регистрации) только по номеру телефона. Потому, что в систему может придти не тот Иванов с которым я бы хотел дружить. А придти другой человек с таким же телефоном - не может

Comment: `я бы поостерегся делать запросы "на будущее" по какому то не ключевому атрибуту (т.е. не по номеру телефона)` - а это ограничение должно устанавливаться формой заявки на подружиться. Понятно, что для заявки на адрес не существующего на момент создания заявки пользователя она должна быть гораздо более строгой. Но тем не менее там тоже вполне возможны альтернативы (телефон, скайп, аська, мыло, аккаунт гугла и т.п.) - номер телефона далеко не единственный из атрибутов профиля, не допускающий (формально) дублирования.

Comment: @Akina Формально - да. А ТС, который делает не социальную сеть, а систему определения местоположения друзей, для которой телефон и является основой (т.к. именно он определяет местоположение) это может быть излишним. Хотя это, конечно, ему решать.